# Protractor-Cucumber order of tests execution

Tags: protractor, cucumber

I'm writing automatic tests for my application using Protractor-Cucumber framework.

I have several feature files with multiple scenarios each and I want to manage the order of their execution using Cucumber tags.
Obviously, all the scenarios fall into the "FullRegression" category, but I also want to mark some of them with the "SmokeTest" tag to be run daily.
The problem is that those "Smoke" scenarios are scattered all over the features and they need to be executed in particular order to work properly.

For example, I want to run scenarios 2 and 3 from Feature2, then run scenario 1 and 2 from Feature1 and then run scenario 5 from Feature3.

Is it possible to do that using Cucumber tags? I've tried it but it didn't work as I expected. The only other idea I have is to create special "SmokeTest.feature" file but then I would need to repeat a lot of scenarios inside it.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cucumber is designed so that all scenarios are independent of each other and cannot be connected together. Each scenario starts from scratch, clearing out the session, emptying the database etc.. This is standard practice for all the major test frameworks (idempotence)

So there is no easy way to do what you want, and more importantly doing what you want has no meaning.

Now some people take great pains to work around this (particularly some Cucumber users), so maybe thats happened with your test suite, but again this is a really bad thing to do.

If you want to combine scenarios you should write new scenarios that use the steps of the scenarios you want to combine e.g.

```
Scenario: Foo
  When I foo
end

Scenario: Bar
  When I bar
end

# This is the one you would write
Scenario: Foo bar
  When I foo
  And I bar
end
```